# how to fix "converting to 'const String' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'String::String(int, unsigned char)'" error in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, syntax-error

Using an Arduino. I have this code to read a file line by line as a string. This string is then inserted into an http url string. Here is the code. All of this except 'File.....' and 'String addr1' go inside the loop

```
String addr1 = "https://docs.google.com/forms/.......................14=happy";
String sd_data;
File testfile; // these parts come before void setup()
testfile = SD.open("testdata.txt", FILE_READ); //goes in the loop
while (testfile.available()) {
sd_data = testfile.readStringUntil('\n');

sd_data.replace(' ', '+'); // replace spaces with +
addr1.replace('happy', sd_data);
}
```

I get this error
converting to 'const String' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'String::String(int, unsigned char)'

Comment: `'happy'` or `"happy"`?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: `'happy'` is an integer.  Certainly code should be using a string  `"happy"` - somehow.

Comment: does that mean `sd_data.replace(' ', '+');` is wrong? @chux

Comment: `' '` and `'+'` are `char`.  Uncertain about [Arduino replace()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/replace/).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, delete

```
String addr1=.........
```

instead of

```
addr1.replace('happy', sd_data);
```

put

```
String var="https://docs.google.com/forms/.......................14="+sd_data;
```